# What is the chance that a supercomputer finds a Seed with money

Tags: seed

I know that today it is almost impossible to find someones Seed. But what happens in the future. Will it ever be possible that a very fast supercomputer is checking million seeds per second to find Seeds with a balance. Maybe someday it will be like bitcoinmining for the people. They let many supercomputer run and if one of them finds a balance it will send the funds directly to the address of the miner...

Comment: 100%—People are stupid and will pick non-random seeds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The probability of finding a special seed is 27^81 = 8.71 * 10^115.

If we assume that there are 1 trillion seeds, the probability of finding a seed with a balance is 8.71 * 10^103 .

If we assume now a Computer can scan 1 Billion Seeds per second, it would take him 2.7647654 * 10^87 Years, to find one seed with a balance.

This is a pretty long time, I think we are save.

Answer (score 4):

First, `Iota` seeds consists of **81-trytes (243-trits)** with have three levels of safety [ 1]:

> A security level determines the number of rounds for hashing, which means that a single seed can have 3 different accounts.
>
> 81-trits (low security)
>   162-trits (medium security)
>   243-trits (high security)
>
> Technically speaking, a single seed has 3 accounts. The same key index on a different security level returns a completely different address. Make sure you keep track of your security levels similarly to your key indexes, as it will be needed for spending your inputs [ 6].

A seed of **81 trytes** results in :

> 87189642485960958202911070585860771696964072404731750085525219437990967093723439943475549906831683116791055225665627 possible probabilities

or 
 [image] [ 2]

**Very important:**

> To "hack" an address one needs to try random seeds, a single attempt can succeed with `1/(27^81)` probability because it depends on the number of the addresses, not on the number of the seeds [ 3]

By the fact that `IOTA` using **Winternitz's unique signatures** (post-quantum signature) [ 1] [ 4] [ 5] You can not use the [Shor Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shor%27s_algorithm) to reduce complexity or attempts, as you can with a Bitcoin address that uses `Elliptic Curve Cryptography`, for example.

It is a consensus among cryptologists that any value above `2^80` is computationally infeasible. So, by answering your question, **the chance of a supercomputer finding a seed is pretty remote.** Since a quantum computer does not take advantage of an ordinary computer, in this case

As for security levels, I'm not sure. But, as far as I know, they generate one more delay in the attempts since they are levels of hash rounds. And this (I'm not sure of the following statement) increases **hashspace** for `^security level` (This **is not** the amount of possible seeds) and `*security level` by attempts

**e.g. (Hashspace increment)**

- 81 trits => `27^81 ^1 (low security)`
- 162 trits => `27^81 ^2 (medium security)`
- 243 trits => `27^81 ^3 (high security)` **[Citation needed]**

**e.g. (Attempts increment)**

- 81 trits => `1* 27^81 attempts (low security)`
- 162 trits => `2* 27^81 attempts (medium security)` //Two times more attempts
- 243 trits => `3* 27^81 attempts (high security)` **[Citation needed]**

**References:**

[1 ] https://iota.readme.io/v1.2.0/docs/seeds-private-keys-and-accounts

[2 ] https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=27%5E81

[3 ] [Why aren't seeds longer than 81 trytes more secure?](https://iota.stackexchange.com/questions/249/why-arent-seeds-longer-than-81-trytes-more-secure/257#257)

[4 ] https://eprint.iacr.org/2011/191.pdf

[5 ] https://www.e-reading.club/bookreader.php/135832/Post_Quantum_Cryptography.pdf#page=45

[6 ] http://learn.iota.org/tutorial/generating-addresses-learn-the-basics

Comment: For those who voted negative. Could you give me more information so that I can improve my answer?